Part name of this IC - Analog Devices, 8-pin, "S 6B" A 06" "C 42"
I want to know the part numbers of the components marked as shown in the attached image.



Marking "S6B" : ADG721BRM
Marking "A06" : AD8629ARMZ
Marking "C42" : AD7787BRMZ
pictures from LCSC:




Thank you very much
